# How to throw an exception using lambda with a List?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, lambda

I'm trying to build a SpringBoot API

Using some examples, I was able to create my own repository, extending JpaRepository. I'm also using a h2 database.

In this repository, I was able to customize my queries, as you guys can see in the code block below. When implementing a method that returns an Optional of my custom class, everything works OK. The problem is when I try to return a List of my custom class. I'm having a hard time to implement exception handling in lambda.

FindUserByUserId can bring multiple entries, but findByName can bring only one.

My repository Interface:

```
package com.augusto.mealservice.Repository;

import com.augusto.mealservice.Entities.Meal;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Repository
public interface MealRepository extends JpaRepository<Meal, Long> {
    public Optional<Meal> findByName(String name);
    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM meals WHERE user_id = ?1 AND meal_date = ?2", nativeQuery = true)
    public List<Meal> findByUserId(long userId, Date date);
}
```

My Service Class:

```
    public ResponseEntity<Meal> getAllMealsByUserId(Long userId, Date date) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        Meal meal = mealRepository.findByUserId(userId, date).orElseThrow(() -> new EmptyListException ("User :: " + userId  + " has no meals registered at " + date));
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(meal);
    }
```

I know that orElseThrow is a method from Optional, not list.

I'm trying to implement a simple, lambda error handling, just like it would work to an Optional return, but with List (everything I'm checking is if the list is empty).

Tried already to call .isEmpty(), but it also don't work.

Can you guys help me?

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're asking. `findByUserId` returns a `List`. If it's empty (`isEmpty()` returns true), just throw your exception.

Comment: `findByUserId` returns a `List<Meal>` but you're attempting to set it to a `Meal`, that's not going to work.

Comment: You also shouldn't be mixing responsibilities. `ResponseEntity` is _strictly_ a Web concept, and the exact responsibility of the Web controller is to translate Web interactions into the internal API of your system. Nothing outside your controller (or other MVC components such as `@ExceptionHandler`s) should touch `ResponseEntity`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that:

```java
public ResponseEntity<List<Meal>> getAllMealsByUserId(Long userId, Date date) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
   List<Meal> meals = 
      mealRepository.findByUserId(userId, date);
   if(meals.isEmpty()) {
     throw new EmptyListException ("User :: " + userId  + " has no meals registered at " + date);
   }
   return ResponseEntity.ok().body(meals);   
}
```

But indeed avoid returning `ResponseEntity` type via your service layer.
 Just return the list of meals is cleaner.

Answer (score -1):

**CollectionUtils** from apache common-collections will help.

```
List<Meal> mealLst = mealRepository.findByUserId(userId, date);
if(CollectionUtils.isEmpty(mealLst)){
//throw your exception
}
```

if there is no record for the *userId*, the repository will return *null*. So in this case null.isEmpty is quite impossible.

Inside CollectionUtils.isEmpty will be:

```
public static boolean isEmpty(Collection coll) {
        return coll == null || coll.isEmpty();
    }
```

Hope it helps!!